# Credential validation was not successful: Unable to connect to localhost:8080 from hawkular connection

Tags: monitoring, hawkular

My connection to hawkular-services-dist-0.30.0.Final of managiq ui is failed. But my manageiq configuration seems to be successful. I can examine the manageiq UI with below url, https://localhost:8443/ (The configuration ref site is http://www.manageiq.org/docs/get-started/docker). However in middleware tab of manageiq UI, adding new middleware provider always throws this message,

```
Credential validation was not successful: Unable to connect to localhost:8080
```

Please check the following captured pic.

[image]

Even more I have no idea which log files of manageiq container have this error statements.

### Update

The ssl error message is shown below,

```
[Tue Feb 07 11:15:25.015949 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 23] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for localhost:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Feb 07 11:15:25.041695 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 23] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for localhost:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Feb 07 11:15:30.667617 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 134] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 0.0.0.0:3000 (0.0.0.0) failed
[Tue Feb 07 11:15:30.667658 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 134] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (0.0.0.0) for 60s
[Tue Feb 07 11:15:30.667693 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 134] [client 172.17.0.1:42666] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 0.0.0.0
[Tue Feb 07 11:15:30.727713 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 137] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 0.0.0.0:3000 (0.0.0.0) failed
[Tue Feb 07 11:15:30.727756 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 137] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (0.0.0.0) for 60s
[Tue Feb 07 11:15:30.727766 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 137] [client 172.17.0.1:42672] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 0.0.0.0
[Tue Feb 07 11:15:30.740819 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 135] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 0.0.0.0:3000 (0.0.0.0) failed
[Tue Feb 07 11:15:30.740878 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 135] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (0.0.0.0) for 60s
[Tue Feb 07 11:15:30.740893 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 135] [client 172.17.0.1:42678] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 0.0.0.0
[Tue Feb 07 11:15:36.283437 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 139] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 0.0.0.0:3000 (0.0.0.0) failed
[Tue Feb 07 11:15:36.283474 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 139] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (0.0.0.0) for 60s
[Tue Feb 07 11:15:36.283483 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 139] [client 172.17.0.1:42684] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 0.0.0.0
[Tue Feb 07 11:15:44.561119 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 140] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 0.0.0.0:3000 (0.0.0.0) failed
[Tue Feb 07 11:15:44.561154 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 140] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (0.0.0.0) for 60s
[Tue Feb 07 11:15:44.561162 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 140] [client 172.17.0.1:42692] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 0.0.0.0
[Tue Feb 07 11:16:07.212882 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 557] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for localhost:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Feb 07 11:16:07.254083 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 557] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for localhost:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show the logs of hawkular-services ?
Did you create the "jhwang" user without errors ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Lucas. My add-user.sh command was successfully executed with no error, and ManageIQ failed to connect hawkular service,so error log was added on the side of manageiq docker container (/var/www/miq/vmdb/log/apache/ssl_error.log) The contents of error logs are shown on the above **UPDATE** part.

Comment: Can you test to query with your user directly into the hawkular-services endpoint ? (A curl using your new user could be enough).

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug, if you can open a JIRA on https://issues.jboss.org with the log details, perhaps we can investigate more and attach there relevant info relative of your scenario.

Comment: I opened this issue on JIRA. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/HAWKULAR-1195?jql=project%20%3D%20HAWKULAR